# ANTLR Lexer Substring

Tags: antlr, lexer

Is there a way of defining a Lexer rule like:

```
DESCRIPTOR :   'INIT'(.)*'END';
```

So DESCRIPTOR returns the content between the two labels INIT and END?

I guess I can use return values, such as:

```
DESCRIPTOR returns [String content]
@init {
   content="";
}: 'INIT'(.)*'END';
```

But I don't get how I can access to such value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that lexer rules (the ones start start with a capital) cannot have a `returns` clause, only parser rules can.

But the rule:

```
DESCRIPTOR :   'INIT' (.)* 'END';
```

works just fine. By default, ANTLR matches `.*` and `.+` reluctantly (ungreedily), so the rule above matches "INIT" followed by zero or more chars until the first `"END"`.

### EDIT

Ah, you want to strip the `"INIT"` and `"END"` from the token. You can do that as follows:

```
DESCRIPTOR 
 : 'INIT' .* 'END' {setText($text.substring(4, $text.length() - 3));}
 ;
```

where `$text` is short for `getText()` (i.e. the entire string the token matched).

Comment: Thanks, Bart. Imagine I've got the following sentence INIT this is a test END.  I'd like to now if I can get just the "this is a test" text.